# How to solve my authentication issue (osm server creation)

Tags: openstreetmap, ubuntu-server

i'm trying to set up an Openstreetmap server on my ubuntu server, which is on a virtual machine.

According to this: http://tuts.syrinxoon.net/tuts/installer-un-serveur-cartographique-avec-openstreetmap, i've done everything. still it doesn't work.

I checked the rendered log.
Here is what comes from the ouput of `renderd -f`

```
renderd[13129]: Rendering daemon started
renderd[13129]: Parsing section renderd
renderd[13129]: Parsing render section 0
renderd[13129]: Parsing section mapnik
renderd[13129]: Parsing section default
renderd[13129]: config renderd: unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[13129]: config renderd: num_threads=4
renderd[13129]: config renderd: num_slaves=0
renderd[13129]: config renderd: tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[13129]: config renderd: stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[13129]: config mapnik:  plugins_dir=/usr/lib/mapnik/2.0/input
renderd[13129]: config mapnik:  font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
renderd[13129]: config mapnik:  font_dir_recurse=0
renderd[13129]: config renderd(0): Active
renderd[13129]: config renderd(0): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[13129]: config renderd(0): num_threads=4
renderd[13129]: config renderd(0): tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[13129]: config renderd(0): stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[13129]: config map 0:   name(default) file(/etc/mapnik-osm-data/osm.xml) uri(/osm/) htcp() host()
renderd[13129]: Initialising unix server socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[13129]: Created server socket 4
renderd[13129]: Renderd is using mapnik version 2.0.0
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
renderd[13129]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf
Running in foreground mode...
renderd[13129]: Starting stats thread
renderd[13129]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "osm"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "osm" (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/etc/mapnik-osm-data/osm.xml')
renderd[13129]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "osm"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "osm" (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/etc/mapnik-osm-data/osm.xml')
renderd[13129]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "osm"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "osm" (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/etc/mapnik-osm-data/osm.xml')
renderd[13129]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "osm"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "osm" (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/etc/mapnik-osm-data/osm.xml')
```

I believe the problem is at the end of this log.
authentication failed for user osm, but i don't really know what it means.
the user osm has a password, which is also "osm"

So does someone has an idea of what could be wrong ?
thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing to connect to your database - you need to make sure the database username and password in your mapnik stylesheet are correct.

Comment: Check my answer just below ;) i don't have this problem anymore. still when i try to display my map, i switch on local tiles, and chrome give me that (failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for each image it's trying to fetch, any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Got it ;)

i just needed to modify that file `/etc/mapnik-osm-data/inc/datasource-settings.xml.inc` to fill it with right informations about database ;)